# unable to use div tag inside composite components

Tags: java, netbeans, jsf-2, facelets

I wrote the following code and save it as a separate file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<ui:composition
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <div id="crb_header">
     <br/>
     <h4 align="right">Welcome : #{homebean.user}</h4>
     <br/>
    </div>
</ui:composition>
```

The above page is attached to the main page using`ui:include` and the following warning messages are visible at the end of the main page.

```
Warning: This page calls for XML namespace declared with prefix div but no taglibrary exists for that namespace.
Warning: This page calls for XML namespace declared with prefix h4 but no taglibrary exists for that namespace.
Warning: This page calls for XML namespace declared with prefix br but no taglibrary exists for that namespace.
Warning: This page calls for XML namespace declared with prefix br but no taglibrary exists for that namespace.
```

Can't we use html tags inside this `ui:composition` files?

Comment: Please note that it has always worked and that those are just XML parser warnings, no errors. They won't appear when JSF project stage is not set to `Development`. They also won't appear in combination with certain XML parsers (read: certain appservers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Didn't you miss to include the xhtml namespace inside the `ui:composition`?

```
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
```

Comment: xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" was missing indeed. Now it works. Many Thanks :)